# update elasticsearch record using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I can connect to and select the first record from an index. But I need to update the record with "newval" parameter. And update method is failing with error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

Here is the code

```
import elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import helpers
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch('http://172.31.73.228:9200')

myquery={"query": {"match_all": {}}}
res = es.search(index="packetbeat-2017.06.12", body=myquery)

for i in range(2):
    print (res['hits']['hits'][i] )
```

The record returned that I need to update:

```
{'_index': 'packetbeat-2017.06.12', '_type': 'flow', '_id': 'AVyZmvuW4pXRFgxKGB7c', '_score': 1.0, '_source': {'@timestamp': '2017-06-12T00:01:30.000Z', 'beat': {'hostname': 'ip-172-31-73-228', 'name': 'ip-172-31-73-228', 'version': '5.4.1'}, 'dest': {'ip': '172.31.73.228', 'port': 9200, 'stats': {'net_bytes_total': 10015, 'net_packets_total': 46}}, 'final': True, 'flow_id': 'EAT/////AP//////CP8AAAFzfHHGrB9J5JLr8CM', 'last_time': '2017-06-12T00:00:30.732Z', 'source': {'ip': '115.124.113.198', 'port': 60306, 'stats': {'net_bytes_total': 141066, 'net_packets_total': 81}}, 'start_time': '2017-06-12T00:00:30.732Z', 'transport': 'tcp', 'type': 'flow'}}
```

my update method:

```
mybody={'doc': {'newval': 24}}

es.update('packetbeat-2017.06.12', 'flow', 'AVyZmvuW4pXRFgxKGB7c', body=mybody, params=None)
```

I am not able to add "newval" variable to the above record.

Comment: Why do you pass ```params=None```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet works correctly:

```
import elasticsearch
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch('http://localhost:9200')

res = es.search(index="packetbeat-2017.06.12", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})

for single in res['hits']['hits']:
    print (single)

es.update('packetbeat-2017.06.12', 'flow', 'AVyZmvuW4pXRFgxKGB7c', body={'doc': {'newval': 24}})
```

Please consider avoiding doing this kind of request.
Check the documentation about [update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html).